# Erlang: Search through list for matching string

Tags: string, list, erlang

Hopefully this is what my problem is(having problem reading the error log that erlang prints). I'm trying to search through a list to find a matching string(PID from a client converted to a string) but it just results in a crash.

```
...
#7 ClientPID = pid_to_list(From),
#8 list:member(ClientPID, #server.users), % 'users' being a list in the record 'server'
...
```

The 'users' list in the 'server' record is just defined to users = [], if it helps.

Crash report:

```
** Reason for termination ==
** "{undef,[{list,member,[\"<0.568.0>\",2],[]}, {server,loop,2,[{file,\"server.erl\"},{line,8}]},
{genserver,loop,2,[{file,\"c:/Erlang/ServCli/genserver.erl\"}{line,13}]}]}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Module is called `lists` not `list`. It's common mistake :)

And your argument are little off.  You are using record, and proper usage look like this: `VariableThatStoresRecord#record_name.filed_name`.  In your case it could be something like `State#state.users` (or just shorten `State` parameter in `loop` function to `S` if you don't like this double state).

What you are doing is actually a semantic suger, which returns on which element in record/tuple given field is stored (since all records are in fact tuples).  In you case `#state.users` returns `2` (first element is record name, and I guess that `users` is first defined field in your record).

Regarding the error message. First thing is thing you get `undef` error.  So it means that you are meking call to undefined function (which is quite common, since Erlang is dynamic language). Than you get list of tuples, which represents call-trace, from newest to oldest like this

```
[ { function call definition }
  { function call definition }
  { function call definition } ]
```

The first one is most interesting, since it is the call to undefined function.  You can see that it is call to module `list` and function `member`. Other than that you can expect either actual arguments, or just arrity (those variables could be garbage collected already in erlang), and some information about function definition (like file and line number).

And from `{list,member,[\"<0.568.0>\",2],[]}` you can see that you are trying to call `list:member` function, with arguments `"<0.568.0>"` and `2`. If you change your call to `lists:member(ClientPID, Server#server.users)` it should work.

Since most of the error messages are usually nested tuples/lists, which are hard to read if they are presented in one line.  So what I do is copy them to my editor, split the one-liner into multiple lines, and than auto indent (emacs does this really great, and some editor can follow this lisp-like indention for Erlang).